# What happens to VSCode extension on user's computers if it's unpublished?

Tags: vscode-extensions

Does the latest downloaded version live on users' machines forever? Or does it get automatically removed on the next update cycle?

Comment: It simply leaves there. If you want such to be removed, you need other mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

The unpublished extension will remain on users' machines.

If you plan to republish your extension with the same extension ID, you can inform users to do a clean-up before installing the extension again:

Windows:

```
cd %USERPROFILE\.vscode\extensions
rm -rf <extension-directory>
```

Mac & Linux:

```
cd ~/.vscode/extensions
rm -rf <extension-directory>
```